# Wildfly - Deployment failed and was rolled back

Tags: wildfly

I am getting the below error while using the wildfly plugin.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (deploy) on project DreamFolks: Deployment failed and was rolled back. -> [Help 1]
```

JBoss/Wildfly is up and running fine and I could not find any ERROR/SEVERE in the jboss logs.
I don't find anything apart from the above error in my Jenkins console.
This job was executed earlier without any issues but it is breaking now.
Please advise.

JBoss version: 7.0
JDK: 8
Checked the port, JBOSS logs, etc

Comment: Can you try a newer version, 4.0.0.Final would be the latest you can use, which should provide a better error message? You should also see an error message in the `server.log`.

Comment: I have tried but got Error says - UndeployMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: Ah, sorry. 4.0.0.Final requires Java 11. If you have to use Java 8 then you'd want to use 3.0.2.Final.